# Javascript Simplify functions with short circuit

Tags: javascript

I am creating a shift schedule and works well so far but I want to simply the amount of functions I have and don't want a function for each shift variation - each shift changes to two other users every Monday.

So far I have `calcShift` and `calcShift2` but this would grow too much for each new date!

```
function calcShift (u) {
    //Return dates for all mondays for the current month
    let mondays = monthsMondays();
    console.log(mondays);
    //for each monday if any match a date - manual for now - then for each specified user return the shift
    for(let m=0; m < mondays.length; m++){
    switch (mondays[m]() === '12/04/2021') {
        case u == 1:
          return '10-6'; 
          break;
        case u == 2:
          return '2-10'; 
          break;
        default:
          return mX()[0];
      }
    }//forloop
  }//function

function calcShift2 (u) {
  let mondays = monthsMondays();
  console.log(mondays);
    //for each monday if any match a date - manual for now - then for each specified user return the shift
    for(let m=0; m < mondays.length; m++){
        //19/04
        if(u ==2){
            if(futureMondays(7) === '19/04/2021'){
                  return '10-6'; 
            } 
        }
        if(u ==3){
          if(futureMondays(7) === '19/04/2021'){
                return '2-10'; 
          } 
        }
    }  
    //all other cases give the standard shift
    return mX()[0]; 
}                                                                                                 
     function createTbla (){
    let uTbl = '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">';
    //loop for users
    uTbl += '<tr><td>' + 'Staff' + '</td><td>' + oldMondays() + '</td><td>' + futureMondays(7) + '</td><td>' + futureMondays(Number(7*2)) + '</td><td>' + futureMondays(Number(7*3)) + '</td><td>' + futureMondays(Number(7*4)) + '</td><td>' + futureMondays(Number(7*5)) + '</td><td><table class="table table-hover table-bordered tbl-qa><tbody id="table-body"><tr class="table-row" id = "table-row"></tr>  <tr><td id="xCol" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td></tr> </tbody></table>'
    '</td> </tr>';
         for(let u=0; u<users.length; u++){
             uTbl += '<tr><td>' +  users[u] + '</td><td>' + calcShift([u]) + '</td><td>' +calcShift2([u]) + '</td><td>' + calcShift3([u])+ '</td><td>' + calcShift4([u]) + '</td><td>' + calcShift5([u]) + '</td><td>' + calcShift6([u]) + '</td></tr>';
    }
    uTbl += '</table';
    document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = uTbl;
}  createTbla();
```

I've also got options between the While, For and Switch loops. Which is most efficient?

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Use a data structure to store shifts by date and user, not a set of functions. Default for a `Map` or object literal.

Comment: Thanks to both. I'll add it to code review site. @Bergi did you mean like a grid? i.e. if(mondays[0])
  table.push({"Date": mondays[0],"Shift":shifts[0], "user": users[0]});
  table.push({"Date": monday2[0],"Shift":shifts[1], "user": users[1]});   //this is fine but I'll still need to 4 to 5 functions or blocks to cover each monday per grid (5 dates per grid) and also means more code lines to change in future. I do believe however this is a suitable data structure.